# How do I check if data exists in node express app

Tags: node.js, express

am working on a node / express app and currently trying to check if some session data exists or not.

To call the session data I'm currently using {{ if data['username'] }}
which works fine. To user a conditional if the data exists the following seems to work:

`{% if data['username'] %} 
do this
{% endif %}`

However I'm not sure how to do something if it DOESN'T exist. Such as

`{% if data['username'] != '' %}`

Any ideas appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What does the documentation of the template engine you're using says? Any examples online you researched for a conditional print?

Comment: This question is about templating. Mention templating engine used.

Comment: And PS: `val != ''` means it does *not* exists, or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Nunjucks here based on the templating, and with that you can do:

```
{% if not data['username'] %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Many thanks, yes forgot to write Nunjucks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the templating language you’re using.
If it’s Twig you can use `not` or `empty`

```
{% if not data['username'] or data['username'] is empty %}
Do this
{% endif %}
```